# How to fix this- error: Invalid use of className::className?

Tags: c++, oop, object

Getting the error: invalid use of className::className.

Was trying to make a timeStamp class which represented a time of a day, it stores seconds, minutes, hours in specific variables. Ran into an **error in line #13 on main function**, the error reads: **invalid use of timeStamp::timeStamp** what did i do wrong?
There's a header file where all the methods are declared.

**The source file cpp:**

```
    #include "timeStamp.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

timeStamp::timeStamp()
{
    Hour = 0;
    Minute = 0;
    Second =0;
}
timeStamp::timeStamp(int h, int m, int s){

Hour = h;
Minute = m;
Second = s;

}
int timeStamp::getHour(){

return Hour;
}

int timeStamp::getMinute(){
return Minute;
}
int timeStamp::getSecond(){
return Second;
}

bool timeStamp::operator!=(timeStamp t){

    if (Second ==t.Second && Minute ==t.Minute && Hour ==t.Hour)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

void timeStamp::Print()
{
    std:: cout<<"Hour:"<<Hour<<"\nMinute:"<<Minute<<"\nSecond:"<<Second<<std::endl;
}
```

**Main:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "timeStamp.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    timeStamp obj1, obj2;
    int h,m,s;

        cout<<"Give hour minute and second:";
        cin>>h>>m>>s;
        obj1.timeStamp(h,m,s); //error
        cout<<"Give H M S";
        cin>>h>>m>>s;
        obj2.timeStamp(h,m,s);

        bool isEqual = obj1 ! = obj2;
        cout<<isEqual<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how you construct objects.

You have to give constructor arguments at the point of definition.

You can't call the constructor like a function later.

```
int main()
{
    int h,m,s;

    cout<<"Give hour minute and second:";
    cin>>h>>m>>s;
    timeStamp obj1(h,m,s);

    cout<<"Give H M S";
    cin>>h>>m>>s;
    timeStamp obj2(h,m,s);

    bool isEqual = obj1 ! = obj2;
    cout<<isEqual<<endl;
}
```

I'm sure that your book goes into more detail about this.